# Can/does hyphenation ignore accents?

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

LuaLaTeX MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[textwidth=6.5in,textheight=9in,nohead,headheight=39pt,headsep=12pt,
            top=72pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{X|X}
    Е́сли вы изу́чите ру́сский язы́к, вы полу́чите хоро́шую пабо́ту.
    & If you master (will master) Russian, you will get a good job. \\

    Е́сли вы изу́чите ру́сский язы́к, вы по\-лу́\-чите хо\-ро́\-шую пабо́ту.
    & If you master (will master) Russian, you will get a good job. \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Notice that I've used U+0301, "combining acute accent," to add accents to the Russian.  (Showing where the accents are is common in English texts designed for learning Russian.)  Here's the Russian half (the left half of the table) from the resulting PDF:

[image: Russian results]

On the first row of the table I get `Underfull \hbox (badness 6332) in paragraph at lines 19--19`, presumably because LuaLaTeX doesn't know how to hyphenate the words with added accents.  If I explicitly hint the hyphenation, as I did on the second row, it gets hyphenated correctly.

Is there any way to tell LuaLaTeX/Polyglossia/whatever to ignore the added accents when hyphenating words?

Comment: As David says, you need to tell the engine what language is to be used: if English is the current language, the engine doesn't know how to hyphenate Russian. It seems that XeLaTeX is able to ignore the combining accent when choosing hyphenation points, whereas LuaLaTeX isn't.

Comment: @egreg my original plan was to dynamically modify the pattern file to add the combining accent everywhere as luatex can load pattern files late but didn't try that the word hyphenated anyway 9in a different place)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It seems not needed. I assumed that `\hyphenrules{russian}` works the same in XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX; it seems not the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know ployglossia but if I explicitly select russian the word is hyphenated:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[textwidth=6.5in,textheight=9in,nohead,headheight=39pt,headsep=12pt,
            top=72pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}


\begin{document}
%
%\input{hyph-ru}

\begin{tabu}{X|X}
    %\hyphenrules{russian}
    \leavevmode\selectlanguage{russian}\righthyphenmin=3 \lefthyphenmin=2
    Е́сли вы изу́чите ру́сский язы́к, вы полу́чите хоро́шую пабо́ту.
    & If you master (will master) Russian, you will get a good job. \\

    Е́сли вы изу́чите ру́сский язы́к, вы по\-лу́\-чите хо\-ро́\-шую пабо́ту.
    & If you master (will master) Russian, you will get a good job. \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With XeLaTeX, but not with LuaLaTeX, it seems. Probably `\begin{tabu}{>{\hyphenrules{russian}}X|X}` is better.

Comment: @egreg the image was made with lulatex?

Comment: Doh! Quirks with `\hyphenrules`, it appears.

Comment: @egreg but with hyphenrules \righthyphenmin gets set (I guess) so hyphenation occurs in same place, i updated my answer thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt.  Today I learned about the `\hyphenrules` command.  Am I right that the consensus is that this only works for XeLaTeX and not LuaLaTeX?  It didn't work here for me using LuaLaTeX, at least.

Comment: @dsedivec No I only used lualatex in my testing, and used it to generate the image shown: I'm not sure what quirk egreg meant, let's ping him...

Comment: @egreg see above comment:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hm, I just copy/pasted your source into a local file, compiled with `lualatex`, and I cannot reproduce your results.  The first row of Russian in my resulting PDF is still not hyphenated, and I still get the underfull warning.  I'm using MacTeX 2013, which seems to be based on TeX Live 2013, and tlmgr reports no available updates.

Comment: Can you try the version I posted originally before @egreg mentioned `\hyphenrules`? If you wait a minute I'll add both versions to the answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK, I just tried it with `\mbox{}\selectlanguage{russian}` instead of `\hyphenrules{russian}` and that did hyphenate, though it chose `полу́чи-те` instead of `полу́-чите` for some reason.  (Compare with my answer using Babel, below.)  Now we're just left wondering if the `\selectlanguage` version didn't work for egreg, and if not, why!  Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: @dsedivec sorry I think I confused myself. I put back the selectlanguage version that was there originally but setting righthyphenmin this time so it breaks as shown. I'm confused though as I used lualatex before to post the image  (but it didn't work today:-)

Comment: Thank you both again!  The real point to take away from this answer is that you have to tell LaTeX what language your text is in with appropriate commands from Babel or Polyglossia.  I think that was obvious to everyone but me.  I'll also add that, at least for Russian, [Babel seems to work fine in LuaLaTeX these days](http://ctan.sharelatex.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/russian/russianb.pdf) (see section 2).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [David Carlisle's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168932/1680) and [egreg's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168924/can-does-hyphenation-ignore-accents/168932?noredirect=1#comment388608_168932) I came up with something that seems to work on my TeX installation:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[main=english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[textwidth=6.5in,textheight=9in,nohead,headheight=39pt,headsep=12pt,
            top=72pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu}{>{\hyphenrules{russian}}X|X}
    Е́сли вы изу́чите ру́сский язы́к, вы полу́чите хоро́шую пабо́ту.
    & discretionary discretionary discretionary discretionary
    discretionary \\

    Е́сли вы изу́чите ру́сский язы́к, вы по\-лу́\-чите хо\-ро́\-шую пабо́ту.
    & discretionary discretionary discretionary discretionary
    discretionary \\
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

The output is now hyphenated properly:

[image: properly hyphenated result]

I changed the English text to words that were likely to need hyphenation, so that I could see if I accidentally broke English hyphenation during testing.

I guess Babel now works under LuaLaTeX.  I thought it did not, which is why I was using Polyglossia.

I'm new to multi-lingual LaTeX documents, so I'm a bit concerned that it looks like I have to manually tell LaTeX what kind of language each section of text is in, despite it being painfully obvious to a human.  I was hoping I could simultaneously load both English and Russian hyphenation rules, and have LaTeX choose which one to use based on the surrounding characters.  Manually marking each little Russian phrase as being in the Russian language is going to kind of suck.

Comment: spotting that the alphabet is cyrillic as opposed to latin could be automated but spotting language is harder, think english and american english or french and spanish or russian and Ukranian. Given a large enough sample google translate (for example) make a reasonable guess but TeX can't really do that.